# How to draw custom widgets in qStyledItemDelegate

Tags: qt, qt5, qstyleditemdelegate

I want to draw custom widgets in my `QListView`. But dont have any clue how to do this.

In all threads until now I read weak suggestions like "Use QListWidget", which is not  an option, because I tried. It is horribly slow. I need to use QListView for efficiency.

So how can I draw such a widget? I could imagine that it has to work with a widget as a member of the delegate and the use of the QSytle/QStylePainter draw primitve and drawcontrol funtions.

Comment: Use `QStylePainter` or `QStyle::draw***` to draw a widget. Override delegate methods to implement interaction with mouse / keyboard.

Comment: The difficulty is, that i want to keep the items customizable with stylesheets. So it would be admirable to be able to put the widgets in an layout and set object names. Could you please make a small example. i have problems to let option.widget.style.drawcontol(ce_widget,... draw anything at all.

Comment: I don't want to make an examples instead of you. Because I'm not working on you ;). You are welcome with direct questions. If you want to support stylesheets you need to do all drawing through `QStyle` and with usage of current `QPalette`.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r: I've been down your path and let me tell you: it's just not worth your time. If you want to have widgets (as in QWidgets) in a list-type view, you will be better off creating your own list widget from scratch via QScrollArea and custom layout logic to place and resize your widgets inside the list. I've done it with very good results.

Comment: The wonderful thing about delegates is that you have access to the item's position and can easily recycle widgets: there are never more widgets than are visible on the screen. Furthermore, the delegate doesn't have to paint: it can position the widget inside the view, and the painting will be done automatically.